# Sending order to print from android

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

I have one problem in android. I have one hotel ordering system app and I am using sql server database for that. When I am giving order from my app it gets max orderid from database and print is generated, but when I have multiple device and giving order from that at a time at that time it getting same order id for all three devices, and order is printing in one print not a different print. It happens because of same order id is inserted. So please help me

Comment: that again depends on your implementation. You need to handle concurrent request. You probably can synchronize the block.

Answer (score 1):

you have to make orderid unique and also auto increment.
when you insert the row in database orderid is autometically generated. you not need to insert it and after row is inserted then get orderid from the db for inserted row user

Comment: but if i am generating orderid unique if i want to get order on same orderid at that time it cant insert in database